# When should I create a hyphenated tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Consider the following two cases:

1. [listview](/questions/tagged/listview) vs. [android-listview](/questions/tagged/android-listview)

   In this case, I believe there is good reason to distinguish between the two, since `listview` has different meanings depending on the context (Android, Microsoft's .NET framework, JavaFX, etc.).
2. [viewpager](/questions/tagged/viewpager) vs. [android-viewpager](/questions/tagged/android-viewpager)

   This is what is confusing me. As far as I can tell, the `ViewPager` class is specific to Android, so why do we need to distinguish between the two?

Could someone please clarify when it is considered acceptable to create and/or make use of hyphenated tags such as the ones above?

Comment: If they are identical, then they should be synonyms (which viewpager and android-viewpager are not).

Comment: Well, practically anyone can create a tag, though it might have to go through a suggested edit. Maybe someone who doesn't use the site much saw the `[android-listview]` tag and thought it was a standard tag naming convention, and you're the first person to notice that both view pager tags exist.

Comment: I will say you use two tags in that case, one for android, and another for listview for example

Comment: @JAngwenyi - What would that accomplish?  With [tag:android-listview], people who are struggling with or experienced with that component can follow and filter on the tag.  With [tag:android] and [tag:listview], you can't follow that component, just generic listviews.  Though the recent edit changes the question, so this should probably be fleshed out into an answer.

Comment: Whoops, the edit only loaded after I'd started composing an answer.  Do you want me to move my post to a separate suggestion for a synonym, and make a more generic answer about when tags should be hyphenated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [listview](/questions/tagged/listview)

Are all [listview](/questions/tagged/listview) questions about a specific framework?  If so, I think the [listview](/questions/tagged/listview) tag should be abolished and replaced with [android-listview](/questions/tagged/android-listview), [wpf-listview](/questions/tagged/wpf-listview), [javafx-listview](/questions/tagged/javafx-listview), etc.  Using the 'related tags' view on the [listview](/questions/tagged/listview) page, I crafted the following query for common frameworks, so we could potentially rework this to use, for example, [android-listview](/questions/tagged/android-listview), [wpf-listview](/questions/tagged/wpf-listview), [asp.net-listview](/questions/tagged/asp.net-listview), etc.  The query removes the following frameworks: [android](/questions/tagged/android),  [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf),  [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net),  [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23),  and [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/listview+-android+-wpf+-asp.net+-c%23+-.net+-jquery

Some 767 questions about a wide variety of list views not refencing any of these most popular frameworks.  We've got [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net), [delphi](/questions/tagged/delphi), [winapi](/questions/tagged/winapi), [qt](/questions/tagged/qt), [sharepoint](/questions/tagged/sharepoint), and a host of others with 10-100 questions each.

What do these questions have in common?  Almost nothing.  None of the first page questions appear to be about implementing or architecting a generic listview.  Why would anyone follow this tag?  Because they love listviews on all platforms? That's sort of ridiculous.

This is not a great tag, but there's not much we can do about it short of adding it to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012.

## [viewpager](/questions/tagged/viewpager)

On the other hand, here's a search for all questions tagged [viewpager](/questions/tagged/viewpager) and not [android](/questions/tagged/android):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/viewpager+-android

7 questions, and they're all actually about Android - they just lack the tag.  Wait a second: OK, now there are no questions which are tagged viewpager and not Android save one for which I've suggested an edit (and which, in retrospect, should probably be closed and deleted).  Check [my activity->revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/325514/kevin-vermeer?tab=activity) if you want to see them.  That's a clear indicator that [viewpager](/questions/tagged/viewpager) should be merged into [android-viewpager](/questions/tagged/android-viewpager).

Comment: Thanks for your input. I just wanted to make sure I was thinking this through correctly... I don't want to create tags if they are not necessary.